# Running "webpack" instead of "node_modules/.bin/webpack"

Tags: webpack, command-line-interface, node-modules

I'm using to run "*node_modules/.bin/webpack*", but I know it's possible to configure the path so that you only have to type "*webpack*". I can't find how, though. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would happen if you install a package [globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally).  For webpack that would be with the command `npm install -g webpack` .`npm` in that case would install Webpack in a set location you can find with `npm root -g`.

If that location is in your  `$PATH`, you can use `webpack` directly on your command line. Do not do that! You would proabably need different versions of webpack for different projects. Instead, if you are using NPM, use `npx webpack` in directory where your project / package.json is. `npx webpack`  is a shortcut to `./node_modules/.bin/webpack.` `npx` is already included with `npm`. Read more [here](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/04/05/npx-the-npm-package-runner.html).

Or another option is to put it in your package.json `scripts` property like:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    }
}
```

Then you can run the local webpack with the [command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) `npm run build`.NPM will then also prefer the local version over a global version if existent.

For more information, read this article: http://ericlathrop.com/2017/05/the-problem-with-npm-install-global/

Comment: As stipulated on the webpack install page (https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#global-installation), it should not be installed globally. Since npx seems to be specifically meant to reach local modules, I assume this is the best answer. Thanks!