# NodeJS - npm install practice

Tags: node.js, npm

Created new folder and did `npm install serve` in it.

It created `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/` folder.

When I run in the same folder `serve` it shows error:

```
command not found: serve
```

What is the way to install?

I am using: `npm@6.5.0`

Comment: Did you create a serve script in your package file? If not, try running `./node_modules/.bin/serve` instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am trying to install and use SERVE package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve`

Comment: I understand that, but unless you install it *globally* (as their docs suggest) you need to do one of the two things I just suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "webpack" instead of "node\_modules/.bin/webpack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566181/running-webpack-instead-of-node-modules-bin-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

My dev environment is MACOS
I read a great many pages on this topic and nothing worked until I tried the following

> ./node_modules/.bin/serve -s build

Also if you are using VS CODE you may want to bring up the terminal window outside of VS CODE - this seems to have snared a lot of people.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should start your project running

```
npm init
```

This will create the `package.json` file.

Then, you can install the serve package globally.

```
npm install -g serve
```

And now you can run `serve`.

Answer (score -1):

If the node.js module has a "command" and you want to run it without installing the module globally(npm install -g serve). You can run it like `./node-modules/.bin/command` from the root folder of the project.

Now, what is generally used is [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx), so that you can from within a project easily run any of the binaries within its local node_modules or your system's global node_modules/ and any other commands on the $PATH.

For example, here we install webpack as a local dependency. You can image doing this in a folder after running `npm init`. Then we run webpack without having to worry about referencing the bin file:

```
$ npm i -D webpack
$ npx webpack
```

Answer (score -1):

The `serve` binary was not found because the operating system cannot locate it in the `PATH` environment variable.

When you do the `npm install serve` command. The `serve` module is only installed into the `node_modules` directory found under the the project folder. Unless you explicitly include the absolute path of this `node_module` directory as part of your `PATH` env var, the `OS` won't know where to find `serve`.

Like others say, the typical practise would be to install the module using the `-g` flag. `G` means global.

When `-g` is used, `npm` will put the binary in its `node` directory somewhere and this this directory would have been included as part of your `PATH` when you install `node`, thus making the any new binary discoverable.